# pass array values from method to method

Tags: java

Hello I am developing a mathematical library for java I wrote methods Matrix(), setMatrix (), getMatrix () is required to getmatrix() method returned the entire two-dimensional array more precisely all its values

```
static int[][] getMatrix(){//return matrix
        return matrix;
}//why returns a reference instead of an array value ? [[I@15db9742 only this
```

```
class Mathematik {

    private static int[][] matrix;
    private static int line_0;
    private static int column_0;

    static int Matrix(int line, int column){//Matrix
        for(int l=0; l<line; l++){//line
            for(int j=0; j<column; j++){//column
                line_0=l;
                column_0=j;
                matrix=new int[l][j];
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    static int setMatrix(int num){//fill matrix
        for(int l=0; l<line_0; l++){//line
            for(int j=0; j<column_0; j++){//column
                matrix[l][j]=num;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static int[][] getMatrix(){//return matrix
        return matrix;
    }//why returns a reference instead of an array value ? [[I@15db9742 only this
}

class Activity{
    Mathematik A=new Mathematik();//call the class

    public static void main(Strin[] args){
        A.Matrix(3,3)//create matrix
        A.setMatrix(10)//to fill in the matrix

        System.out.println(""+A.getMatrix());//Writes the grid values to a string
    }
}
```

arrays 
[1a, 2a, 3a.....a]

the method getMatrix() is required to return all values of the array

Comment: Are you asking how to print a matrix? Why your code doesn't compile? What is your question?

Comment: As a beginner you should not use the word `static` to declare fields.

Comment: Why are you creating a new matrix array inside your nested for loops in your `Matrix` method?  That should be created outside your nested loops. And I'm not certain what that method is supposed to do.

Comment: @jim829б to set the dimension of the matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are requiring the array and that what is returning is correct . You must convert that array to String .Try using `Arrays.toString(matrix);`

The current value that is getting returned is the representation in memory for the matrix value .

Please refer to [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) as [JB Nizet mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

Comment: Or rather, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-

Comment: And it doesn't return a "memory allocation". It returns a reference to the matrix.

Comment: I am updating the answer with your name and the provided link

Comment: yes , what I am saying is that it is the reprezentation of the matrix object in memory . am I wright ?

Comment: yes I did my correction with the word representation

Comment: The hashCode in the Oracle version of Java defaults to the memory address of the object.  The default toString() method returns this in hex.

Comment: The `Arrays.toString()` method won't do what is desired on `matrix` because that method only displays one-d arrays.  The variable matrix is an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

It does return the matrix. You can't print the matrix like you are trying. You need to print each value. Or you can simply iterate over the rows and then pass each one to `Arrays.toString()` to display them. You may also want to write your own display routine for your library.

Comment: @JB Nizet how to translate a string back into a two-dimensional array ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The purpose of the `Arrays.toString()` is to display each row of the matrix.  No translation is needed.

Comment: @JB Nizet  wrote the method summation of the matrix rows translate into values using the method Integer.parseInt(String); writes a java error.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[[50], [50], [50]]"
Zero

Comment: The `Arrays.toString()` method for `int[]` is not designed to be converted to type `int`.  It is simply used to display a list of comma separated values between square braces.  And `Integer.parseInt(String)` only takes a single string of digits and nothing else.  e.g.  `"1234"`.

Comment: Please check the Java API or  [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) on how to use Arrays.toString(), Integer.parse() or any other method.